# IndexError: list index out of range, problems with selecting the elements of a list

Tags: python, list, ros, target, subscriber

I am working on a project for my thesis and in one of my script i am subscribing a ROS message that was created by me. One of the parameters in this message is a list with target information.

```
targets = [x_min: 447
y_min: 821
x_max: 460
y_max: 846
confianca: 0.99702954, x_min: 403
y_min: 839
x_max: 417
y_max: 869
confianca: 0.99742514]
```

This information is organized through other message.

In the script that I am trying to subscribe this message I was using the following line: `variable_name.targets[0]` to access the information of the first target in the list, but when I run the script it gives me this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Not really possible to say without more information such as your callback and what the message definition looks like.

Answer (score 1):

script :

```
lista = []

print(lista[0])
```

output:

```
line 3 , in <script.py>
print(lista[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Maybe your list is empty ?

Comment: No, my list is not empty because when i print the list, the out put is shown above. Moreover, when i use the length function it gives me a number, in this case was 2.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have used the syntax for a `dictionary` instead of a `list`, I might be wrong here, but that seems like the issue to me. Maybe using a `dictionary` will help?

```py
targets = {x_min: 447
y_min: 821
x_max: 460
y_max: 846
confianca: 0.99702954, x_min: 403
y_min: 839
x_max: 417
y_max: 869
confianca: 0.99742514}
```

Comment: question reports:  IndexError: list index out of range ...

Comment: I think it is a list because i print the type of the variable and it shows "list". Moreover, it has a length.

Comment: In my project the x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max and confianca is a 1º message that i created in ROS that organizates the parameters of a target. But since i have man targets, i first organize each one with the 1º message, and the put them all in a list with append. This list is then published.